# Unexpected token in componentDidMount exporting as default

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use componentDidMount and exporting as default but I'm getting the error. Unexpected token, expected ",". This code works when I use the export default class HelpScreen extends React.Component {}, but I need to use the const HelpScreen = () => {}. Here is my code:

```
const HelpScreen = () => {
state = {
    measure: [],
    
} 


componentDidMount () {
    api.get('measures/shower/' + this.state.idShower).then(res => {
        this.setState({measure: res.data.measures})
    }
};
return(
    <View style={styles.screen}>
        <Header></Header>
        <View>
            {this.state.measure.map( function(data, index) {
                return(
                    <View>
                        <Text>{data.startTime} seconds</Text>
                    </View>
                )
            })}
        </View>
        <Dropdown/>
    </View>
)
```

};

I tried to change for

```
    useEffect(() => {
    api.get('measures/shower/' + this.state.idShower).then(res => {
        this.setState({measure: res.data.measures})
    }
})
```

And no success too.
Thanks for all replies.

Comment: `componentDidMount` doesn't *exist* in a function component - it's not a class, it doesn't have methods. You've already replaced its functionality with [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to change for useEffect, but doesn't seems to work. I get the same error.

Comment: Having both won't fix the syntax error if you copy-paste it across! Count your parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [measures] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
    api.get('measures').then(res => {
        // this.setState({measures: res.data.measures})
        this.state.measures = res.data.measures
        this.state.measures.map(x => {
            console.log(some)
        })
    });
});

return(
    <View style={styles.screen}>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
        <View>
            {this.state.measures.map((x) => <Text>{x.WaterConsumption}</Text>)}
        </View>
    </View> 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an empty array in useEffect to get similar functionality as componentDidMount

```
useEffect(()=>{
   // CODE
},[])
```

could make it more sophisticated by listening to navigation to the screen.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const screen_focus = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // CODE
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return screen_focus;
  }, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way (Updated)

```
const HelpScreen = () => {
  const [measure, setMeasure] = useState([]);

  // add this
  useEffect(() => {
    api.get("measures/shower/" + this.state.idShower).then((res) => {
      setMeasure(res.data.measures);
    });
  }, []);

  // remove this
  //componentDidMount(){}

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header></Header>
      <View>
        {measure.map(function (data, index) {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>{data.startTime} seconds</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
      <Dropdown />
    </View>
  );
};

export default HelpScreen;
```

Comment: This seems to work on the first part, but I'm not getting the {data.startTime} value. Looks like that It's not being returned.

Comment: That might be the api response issue `res.data.measures` check data in response which should contain `startTime` in it as you are using it on render